# Select rows with line breaks: Unexpected result

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

**I'm trying to find rows in a table where there are line breaks.**

I found some [sample code](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2223708?start=15&tstart=0) that lets me do this:

`where dump(f1) like '%,10%' and  Not (dump(f1) like '%100%')`

---

However, I'm getting an unexpected result.

```
create table test1 (f1 varchar(25));

insert into test1(f1) values ('Note');
insert into test1(f1) values ('Nota');   --<-- Slight spelling difference

select * from test1 where dump(f1) like '%,10%' and  Not (dump(f1) like '%100%')

F1                       
-------------------------
Note
```

**Why does the query return a record, if there isn't a carriage return? And why does it only return a single record?**

*Prediction: I'm having a brain fart and/or I have no idea what I'm doing. It is Monday morning, after all.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DUMP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions063.htm#SQLRF00635) returns a VARCHAR2.

```
select f1, dump(f1) from test1;

F1            DUMP(F1)
------------- ---------------------------- 
Note          Typ=1 Len=4: 78,111,116,101
Nota          Typ=1 Len=4: 78,111,116,97

2 rows selected.
```

So searching for '%,10%' will only return 'Note' because it's dump representation contains 101, where as 'Nota' does not.

If you insert those values with a return character/line break, the result would be:

```
select  f1, dump(f1)
from test1 where 
dump(f1) like '%,10%' 
and  Not (dump(f1) like '%100%');

F1            DUMP(F1)
------------  -----------------------------------------------
Note          Typ=1 Len=4: 78,111,116,101
Note          Typ=1 Len=5: 78,111,116,101,10
Nota          Typ=1 Len=5: 78,111,116,97,10
```

You get 3 rows returned. The 2 rows ending with ',10' contain the the line breaks.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted a follow-up question & answer here: [Select strings with line breaks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215988/select-strings-with-line-breaks)