# Select strings with line breaks

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

**How can I select strings that have line breaks in them?**

I can think of these possibilities when it comes to line breaks in strings:

```
create table test1 (
    id number(4,0),
    f1 varchar(25));

insert into test1(id,f1) values (1,'a');
insert into test1(id,f1) values (2,chr(10) || 'a');
insert into test1(id,f1) values (3,'a' || chr(10));
insert into test1(id,f1) values (4,'a' || chr(10) || 'a');
insert into test1(id,f1) values (5,'a' || chr(10) || chr(10) || 'a');
insert into test1(id,f1) values (6,chr(10));
commit;
```

`chr(10)` is the value for line breaks.

There might be more possibilities that I haven't thought of.

Comment: you may also want to trap for Chr(13). chr(10) is line feed, 13 is carriage return.

Comment: I refer you to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to ask the result of `dump()` if there is a newline character in the string.  Ask the string directly.

Example `where` clause

```
where f1 like '%' || chr(10) || '%'
```

or

```
where instr(f1,chr(10)) > 0
```

or (Per John A)

```
where regexp_like( f1, chr(10), 'n' )
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dump()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635):

> DUMP returns a VARCHAR2 value containing the datatype code, length in
>   bytes, and internal representation of expr. The returned result is
>   always in the database character set.

```
select 
    id,
    f1,
    dump(f1)
from 
    test1 
where 
    dump(f1) like '%: 10,%'    --Selects #2
    or dump(f1) like '%,10'    --Selects #3
    or dump(f1) like '%,10,%'  --Selects #4,5
    or dump(f1) like '%: 10'   --Selects #6
order by
    id
```

All rows with line breaks are selected. Row #1 is not selected, because it does not have a line break.

[image]

Comment: This should also work: 
select id, f1 from test1
where regexp_like(f1,CHR(10),'n');